How to fix datatable body miisalignment issue in column search filter
I having JQuery datatable with column search and horizondal scroll. When I press tab key in column search  header is moving but table body not moving. below is my code.
     <style>
    .frm {
        /* padding-right: 75px; */
    }

    /* input {
        width: 250px!important;
    } */
    input[type='search'],
    select[name="example_length"] {
        border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    }

    div.dataTables_wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    input[type='search']:focus {
        border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    }

    table.dataTable thead th {
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    table td {
        word-wrap: break-word;
        max-width: 400px;
    }

    #example td {

        text-align: center;
    }

    #example .details {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    table.dataTable thead th,
    table.dataTable thead td {
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    #example_length {
        padding-left: 14px;
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px) {

        .vw {
            width: 250px;
        }
    }

    div.dataTables_scrollBody {
        background: #f2f2f2 !important;
    }

    .dataTables_wrapper.no-footer .dataTables_scrollBody {
        border-bottom: none !important;
    }

    .dt-buttons {
        display: none;
    }

    .exp {
        padding-top: 25px;
        /* width: 50%; */
        /* margin-left: -45px; */
    }
</style>
<table id="example" class="display table-bordered" style="width:100%;">
        <?php $questions = getallquestions($mysql_connectionLinkLocal); ?>
        <thead style="font-size:14px;background: #00a0e4;color: white;">
            <tr>


                <th>Badge Number</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Completion Time</th>
                <?php foreach ($questions as $row) {
                    $qid = $row["id"];

                    $question = $row["questions"]; ?>
                    <?php if ($qid == 16) { ?>
                        <th class="" style=""><?php echo "Recommended Speed"; ?></th><?php } else { ?>
                        <th>v?php echo $question; ?></th>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <th style="">Category</th>
                <!-- <th style="display:none">Speed</th>  -->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php $getentry = getallentry($mysql_connectionLinkLocal, $badgenumber_rtr);
            foreach ($getentry as $row) {
                $lastmodified = $row["last_modified_date"];
                $name = $row["Name"];
                $shift = $row["shift"];
                $firstshiftreporting = $row["FirstShift"];
                $secondshiftreporting = $row["SecondShift"];
                $thirdshiftreporting = $row["ThirdShift"];
                $size = $row["size"];
                $process7mm = $row["7mmprocess"];
                $process9mm = $row["9mmprocess"];
                $machines7mm = $row["7mmFinPress"];
                $machines9mm = $row["9mmFinPress"];
                $slab7mm = $row["7mmSlab"];
                $slab9mm = $row["9mmSlab"];
                $slabs = $row["SLABS"];
                $spm = $row["SPM"];
                $reason = $row["reason"];
                $maxspm = $row["MAXSPM"];
                $downtime = $row["downtime"];
                $category = $row["category"];
                $speed = $row["speed"];
                // $btn = '<a href="index.php?viewanswer=1&answer='.$lastmodified.'&submission='.$subid.'"><button style="font-size:17px;background-color: #2a6a80;border-color: #2a6a80;"  class="btn btn-success" id="" type="button" name="submitviewentries" >View &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-eye"></i></button></a>';
            
                ?>
                <tr>

                    <td class="details"><?php echo $row["BadgeNumber"] ?></td>
                    <td class="details"><?php echo $name ?></td>
                    <td class="details"><?php echo $row["last_modified_date"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $process7mm ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $size ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $shift ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $firstshiftreporting ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $secondshiftreporting ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $thirdshiftreporting ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $machines7mm ?></td>

                    <!-- <td><?php echo $process9mm ?></td> -->

                    <td><?php echo $machines9mm ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $slab7mm ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $slab9mm ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $slabs ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $spm ?></td>
                    <td style=""><?php echo $speed ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $downtime ?></td>
                    <td style="white-space: pre;"><?php echo $reason ?></td>
                    <td style=""><?php echo $category ?></td>
                    <!-- <td style="display:none;"><?php echo $speed ?></td> -->
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>

        </tbody>
    <script>

$(document).ready(function () {
var table=$('#example').DataTable({
// stateSave: true
"ordering": false,
"retrieve": true,
"fixedHeader": true,
"scrollX": true,
// "fixedColumns": {
//    left: 1
//  },
          scrollY: '600px',
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: 'Export',
            title:'Aluminum Coil Production Tracking Entries',
            className: 'btn btn-primary',
            header: true,
            exportOptions: {
                //columns: ':visible:not(.notexport)'
                //columns: [':visible', 16,18,19 ]
                 columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
            }
        }],
       
       
     });
    
     // Apply the search
table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that.search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
} );
} );


on pressing tab key I m getting like above image
but it should be like below image


Are you sure this problem is in any way related to PHP? Did you check the generated markup for problems?

this is not PHP problem. this is CSS problem. columns misaligned due to table body is not scrolling but table header is scrolling on pressing tab key in column search

If this is not a PHP problem, remove the tag and the PHP code and replace it with the code that helps others to reproduce the problem

I have added my style also. i have attached the image how it should look like
